# Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Решил попробовать добавить в приложение лицензии.
Следовал этой инструкции: [ссылка на инструкцию](https://habr.com/post/274859/)

Всё сделал как написано, но вот 5-ый пункт инструкции всё никак не работает.
Пишет:

[image: ошибка]

> *Ошибка:* Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager,
>   java.lang.String)'

Никак не получается решить проблему. Инструкция начала 2016-го. Может в 2018-ом уже нужно писать как-то по другому?

**Вопрос:** как написать чтобы ошибки не возникало?

**UPD1:**

Если заменить `getFragmentManager()` на `getSupportFragmentManager()`, то возникает такая ситуация:
[image: ошибка]

> *Ошибка:* Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

**UPD2:**

**В LicensesDialogFragment:**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class LicensesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{

    public static LicensesDialogFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new LicensesDialogFragment();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_license, null);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/open_source_licenses.html");
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.action_licenses))
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create();
    }
}
```

**В Activity с кнопкой:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class InformationActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_information);


        Button ShowLicensesBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_licensesID);


        ShowLicensesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                displayLicensesDialogFragment();
                           }
        });
    }


    private void displayLicensesDialogFragment() {
        LicensesDialogFragment dialog = LicensesDialogFragment.newInstance();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "LicensesDialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent StartMainActivityIntent = new Intent(InformationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(StartMainActivityIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Метод `getFragmentManager()` у вас объявлен? Судя по коду ошибки нет.

Comment: @Anamnian Хм... Нет. 
А как его объявить? Что-то в инструкции не было ничего про это написано.

Comment: Где находится Ваш метод displayLicensesDialogFragment()? в файле активити?

Comment: пжлста, добавьте ошибку текстом, а не скрином

Comment: @RomanK. Да, в файле активити.

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Фрагменты из android.app - deprecated.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Добавил итог вашего предложения в текст проблемы

Comment: Активити отнаследуйте от AppCompatActivity.

Comment: `InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @YuraIvanov Всё работает, ура. Сердешно благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте вместо `getFragmentManager` суппортный менеджер - `getSupportFragmentManager`.

UPD:

`public class InformationActivity extends Activity` замените на `public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager` выделился красным пишет: _Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'_

Comment: Проверьте импорт в классе LicensesDialogFragment: должен быть import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment. Вы наверное импортнули  import android.app.DialogFragment (не из суппортной)

Comment: Импортировал всё что можно, включая: 
`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`,
`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` и 
`import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`

Comment: а наследовались в LicensesDialogFragment от DialogFragment()?

Comment: Оу, а как это проверить?

Comment: public class LicensesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
И также проверьте чтобы активити наследовалось от активити суппортной

Comment: решение должно работать. Посмотрите, везде ли вы импортировали нужные классы - `support.v4` (в активности и фрагменте)

Comment: @RomanK. Код указал в обновлении текста проблемы.

Comment: `public class InformationActivity extends Activity` замените на `public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @RomanK. Всё заработало. Низкий поклон.